# identifying new line in scanner after an if statement

Tags: java, android

I'm kinda new to android and I've been having a problem with the scanner class especially the `.newline()` since I can not get it to work in the following code java just scans everything in the document without checking the line

```
package com.cal.omida.calupdater;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textv;
    private Button submitButton;
    private String TAG = "got here";
    private String[] stringsarray = {"empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty"};
    private String exp = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainentry);
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.process);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String temp = textv.getText().toString();
                String main = removeTab(temp);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(main);
                String[] finalString = scannerclass(scanner);
                Log.d("found", main);
                for (int io = 0; io<11;io++){
                    exp+=finalString[io]+"\n";
                }
                alert(exp,scanner);
            }
        });

    }

    private String[] scannerclass(Scanner scanner){
        scanner.useDelimiter(";");
        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String text = scanner.next();
            stringsarray[i] = text;
            i++;
        }
        return stringsarray;

    }

    private void alert(String text, final Scanner scanner){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(text);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Add to cal",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //todo add to cal function
                        exp=null;
                        if (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                            scanner.nextLine();
                            String[] finalString = scannerclass(scanner);
                            for (int io = 0; io<11;io++){
                                exp+=finalString[io]+"\n";
                            }
                            alert(exp,scanner);
                        }

                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        exp=null;
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private String removeTab(String main) {
        String main2 = main.replace("\t",";");
        return main2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

just to clarify my code a bit: I have an 11 part line separated by ";" I want to scan each part of the line put it into an array check the data using an alert dialog and if positive adding it to my calendar (still in development) and scan the next line. 
my problem: if I enter less than 11 parts scanner continues to the next line. is there any way to stop this so it just scans the line that it's on and not continue to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to **use one scanner to get each line, then a second scanner to separate each line.**

For example:

```
String main = /*something*/;
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(main); // will scan each line, separated by a newline
while(lineScanner.hasNextLine()){
    Scanner semicolonSeparatedScanner = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine());
    /* work from here */
}
```

Mind, you could even simplify your code further, using String.split:

```
while(lineScanner.hasNextLine()){
    String[] semicolonSeparatedText = lineScanner.nextLine().split(";");
}
```